# Why $\int_{-1}^1 |x|^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx$ doesn't exist?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here's what I did: $\int_{-1}^1 |x|^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx=\int_{-1}^0-x^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx+\int_{0}^1x^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx=\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{5}}}{-\frac{1}{5}}\Biggr|_{-1}^{0}+\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{5}}}{-\frac{1}{5}}\Biggr|_{0}^{1}$.

My textbook says that this integral doesn't exist, is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to switch the sign:
$$\int_{-1}^1 |x|^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx=\int_{-1}^0(-x)^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx+\int_{0}^1x^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx=\\
=\int_{0}^1x^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx+\int_{0}^1x^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx=2\int_{0}^1x^{-\frac{6}{5}}dx>0.$$ 
Now, $x^a$ has a simple primitive, which in this case shows that the integral diverges.

Comment: +1 nice answer!

Comment: But if we solve the integral $\int x^{-\frac{6}{5}} dx$, isn't it equal to $\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{5}}}{-\frac{1}{5}}$?

Comment: @KevinMoore ...and $\lim_{x \to 0} x^{-\frac{1}{5}}$ is equal to.......

Comment: Right, got it. Now I see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can't apply The fundamental theorem of Calculus since $|x|^{-6/5}$ blows up at $x=0$ and so, the conditions of such theorem are not satisfied. Whether you are using improper Riemman integrals or Lebesgue integrals, due to the singularity at $0$ the integration domain should be broken down. Since the integrals is even, it suffices to consider $2\int^1_0|x|^{-5/6}$. Then it becomes much clearer that integrand takes an infinite value.